# Is there a summation formula for this equation (contains square roots, and functions within the square root)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, summation

I am trying to solve a summation formula that is quite complex. However, to make the "answering" process for you guys easier I'll isolate the part I am having trouble with...

The equation is as follows:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{n/h} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ih(2c-ih)}} = \ ?
$$
**NOTE:** 'c' is just a simple constant; if it helps just say 'c = 3' if you need it.

Comment: Should the index really start at $i=0$?

Comment: @graydad oops... that's supposed to be `i=1`

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a Riemann Sum.  What do you know about them?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki to be honest, nothing, I'm only an AP Calculus student in high school who's very interested in math.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The formula above is actually used to solve for the length of a section of a circle, when the equation for the circle is y = sqrt{c^2 + x^2}, and when n=x_f-x_i (x_f is the terminal end of the segment and x_i is the initial)

Comment: That's exactly a problem of integration - in the limit you'll find that what you're doing is (roughly) equivalent to integrating your arc length from one point to another.  The details are a little bit too complicated to go into here; if you're interested in them then I encourage searching around terms like 'arc length integral' and 'riemann integration'.  If you're just interested in solving _this_ problem, try converting to polar coordinates!

Comment: (Also, you probably want $y=\sqrt{c^2-x^2}$; $y=\sqrt{c^2+x^2}$ is a section of the hyperbola $y^2-x^2=c^2$.)

Comment: Your index $i$ goes from 1 to $n/h$. When $i=n/h$, the expression in the square root is $2c-ih = 2c-(n/h)h = 2c-n$. Seems to me that this should be $2n-n$, not $2c-h$. Therefore, shouldn't the expression be $2n-ih$, not $2c-ih$?

Comment: @martycohen My presumption is that it's a _partial_ arc - yours would essentially cover an entire quarter-circle, whereas OP's is an arbitrary arc.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for (I was hoping for something to search for in the library or on the internet). (oh, and thank you for the correction on the circle equation; it was only a typo)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\left[x\right]$
  is the integer part of $x$. For partial summation you have $$\overset{n/h}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ih\left(2c-ih\right)}}=\left[\frac{n}{h}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\left(2c-n\right)}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n/h}\left[t\right]\frac{h\left(2c-th\right)-th^{2}}{\left(th\left(2c-th\right)\right)^{3/2}}dt.$$
 Note that $\left[t\right]\geq1;$
  hence $$\overset{n/h}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ih\left(2c-ih\right)}}\geq\left[\frac{n}{h}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\left(2c-n\right)}}+\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\left(2c-n\right)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{h\left(2c-h\right)}}\right)\underset{h\rightarrow0}{\longrightarrow}+\infty.$$
 P.S. I suppose we are working with real numbers, so I use a right-side limit.

Comment: Ummm..., I need a little help understanding this--I'm only a high school student. Is there a reference that I could use explaining to me what you did? (online source, please). (I would like a reference on how to do this, so I can do it on other problems I have)

Comment: I used the Abel's summation formula (partial summation) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula